# How to see contents of Hive orc files in linux

Tags: linux, bash, compression, hive

Is there a way to see the contents of an orc file that hive 0.11 and above use. I usually cat gz files and decompress them to see the contents 
eg: cat part-0000.gz | pigz -d | more 
Note: pigz is a parallel gz program.

I would like to know if there is something similar to this for orc files.

Comment: Try `pigz -dz` on it.

Comment: pigz says input is not compressed

Comment: The documentation says "The codec can be Snappy, Zlib, or none.".  If it were zlib, and you had the right starting point, then `pigz -dz` would work on it.  It may be Snappy, or you might not have the right starting point.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Updated answer in year 2020**:

Per @Owen's answer, ORC has grown up and [matured](https://orc.apache.org/docs/) as it's own [Apache project](https://orc.apache.org/).  A completed list of [ORC Adopters](https://orc.apache.org/docs/adopters.html) shows how prevalent it is now supported across many varieties of Big Data technologies.

Credit to @Owen and the ORC Apache project team, ORC's project site has a fully maintained up-to-date documentation on using either the [Java](https://orc.apache.org/docs/java-tools.html) or [C++](https://orc.apache.org/docs/cpp-tools.html) stand alone tool on ORC file stored on a Linux local file system.  Which carried on the torch for the original Hive+ORC Apache wiki [page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC).

Original answer dated: `May 30 '14 at 16:27`

> The ORC file dump utility comes with hive (0.11 or higher):
>
> ```
> hive --orcfiledump <hdfs-location-of-orc-file>
> ```
>
> [Source
>   link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC)

Comment: Unfortunately the "-d" argument which actually outputs the data (as opposed to just the metadata) is only available from Hive 0.15.

Comment: FWIW, the original Hive+ORC wiki page now contains a table that identified new features per Hive version that was introduced.  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC#LanguageManualORC-ORCFileDumpUtility

Answer (score 29):

There is now also a native executable for Linux and MacOS that prints the contents of the orc file in JSON. See the ORC project (http://orc.apache.org/) and build the C++ tools.

```
% orc-contents examples/TestOrcFile.test1.orc
```

There is also a native metadata tool:

```
% orc-metadata ../examples/TestOrcFile.test1.orc
```

The ORC project also has a standalone uber jar that can do the same from Java.

```
% java -jar orc-tools-1.2.3-uber.jar data myfile.orc
```

Answer (score 2):

It's also capable to see the contents of a ORC file by desktop application running on Linux.

There is a desktop application to view [Parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/) and also other binary format data like [ORC](https://orc.apache.org/) and [AVRO](https://avro.apache.org/). It's pure Java application so that can be run at Linux, Mac and also Windows. Please check [Bigdata File Viewer](https://github.com/Eugene-Mark/bigdata-file-viewer) for details.

It supports complex data type like array, map, struct, etc.

[image]