# is it possible to read a orcserde hadoop file from command line?

Tags: hadoop, command-line, orc

i am trying to read a ORC file in hadoop file system from command line but the below commands are not working.

hadoop fs -text  is not working

whats equivalent command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you'll have to dump it from Hive. This appears to be a duplicate of this question - [How to see contents of Hive orc files in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847024/how-to-see-contents-of-hive-orc-files-in-linux)

The `hive --orcfiledump <location-of-orc-file>` or something similar depending on your Hive version should do it. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC