# On HDFS, I want to display normal text for a hive table stored in ORC format

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, hdfs, orc

I have saved json dataframe in Hive using orc format

```
jsonDF.write.format("orc").saveAsTable(hiveExamples.jsonTest)
```

Now I need to display the file as a normal text on HDFS. Is there away to do this?

I have used `hdfs dfs -text /path-of-table`, but it displays the data in ORC format.

Comment: Hi! You can follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847024/how-to-see-contents-of-hive-orc-files-in-linux

Comment: Hi @Chema, I have reviewed the link and couldn't get the answer to look the contents of ORC file on HDFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `linux shell` command there is an utility called `hive --orcfiledump`

To see the metadata of an `ORC` file in `HDFS` you can invoke the command like:

```sh
[@localhost ~ ]$ hive --orcfiledump <path to HDFS ORC file>;
```

To see the content of your `ORC` file in plain text you can invoke the command with `-d` option:

```sh
[@localhost ~ ]$ hive --orcfiledump -d <path to HDFS ORC file>;
```

As an example:

```sh
hive> DESCRIBE FORMATTED orders_orc;
Location:  hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse/training_retail.db/orders_orc
# Storage Information        
SerDe Library:          org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde    
InputFormat:            org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat  
OutputFormat:           org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat

hive> exit;

[@localhost ~ ]$ hdfs dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/training_retail.db/orders_orc
Found 1 items
-rwxrwxrwx   1 training hive     163094 2020-04-20 09:39 /user/hive/warehouse/training_retail.db/orders_orc/000000_0

[@localhost ~ ]$ hdfs dfs -tail /user/hive/warehouse/training_retail.db/orders_orc/000000_0
��+"%ў�.�b.����8V$tߗ��\|�?�xM��
                      *�ڣ�������!�2���_���Ͳ�V���
                                                     r�E(����~�uM�/&��&x=-�&2�T��o��JD���Q��m5��#���8Iqe����A�^�ێ"���@�t�w�m�A ���3|�����NL�Q����p�d�#:}S-D�Wq�_"����

[@localhost ~ ]$ hive --orcfiledump /user/hive/warehouse/training_retail.db/orders_orc/000000_0;
Structure for /user/hive/warehouse/training_retail.db/orders_orc/000000_0
File Version: 0.12 with HIVE_8732
20/04/20 10:19:58 INFO orc.ReaderImpl: Reading ORC rows from /user/hive/warehouse/training_retail.db/orders_orc/000000_0 with {include: null, offset: 0, length: 9223372036854775807}
Rows: 68883
Compression: ZLIB
Compression size: 262144
Type: struct<_col0:int,_col1:string,_col2:int,_col3:string>
....
File length: 163094 bytes
Padding length: 0 bytes
Padding ratio: 0%

[@localhost ~ ]$ hive --orcfiledump -d /user/hive/warehouse/training_retail.db/orders_orc/000000_0 | head -n 5
{"_col0":1,"_col1":"2013-07-25 00:00:00.0","_col2":11599,"_col3":"CLOSED"}
{"_col0":2,"_col1":"2013-07-25 00:00:00.0","_col2":256,"_col3":"PENDING_PAYMENT"}
{"_col0":3,"_col1":"2013-07-25 00:00:00.0","_col2":12111,"_col3":"COMPLETE"}
{"_col0":4,"_col1":"2013-07-25 00:00:00.0","_col2":8827,"_col3":"CLOSED"}
{"_col0":5,"_col1":"2013-07-25 00:00:00.0","_col2":11318,"_col3":"COMPLETE"}
```

You can follow this link for details:

[How to see contents of Hive orc files in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847024/how-to-see-contents-of-hive-orc-files-in-linux)

Comment: Thank you @Chema. I was actually trying with partial hdfs file path without giving full file name and was thrown NO FILE EXISTS error. Your example helped me in understanding how it works.