# hive is not returning values from external table in ORC format

Tags: hive, zlib, orc, external-tables

I'm trying to retrieve data from an external table on Hive. I'm doing this using an docker container based on cloudera/quickstart image that is official image of Cloudera.

The table:

```
create external table dev.tru_sprinklr_rpt_platform_inbound_case (
universal_message_id    STRING  COMMENT 'Id unico na mensagem', 
inbound_message_date    STRING  COMMENT 'Data no formato Unix Timestamp', 
message                 STRING  COMMENT 'Mensagem escrita na Rede Social', 
permalink               STRING  COMMENT 'URL que aponta para uma postagem específica na Rede Social', 
social_network          STRING  COMMENT 'Nome da Rede Social', 
associated_cases        STRING  COMMENT 'Id de mensagens associados ao caso (gerado automaticamente pela Sprinklr no periodo de 24 horas)',
from_user               STRING  COMMENT 'Usuario', 
sentiment               STRING  COMMENT 'Sentimento', 
assunto_gestor          STRING  COMMENT 'Categoria gerada na plataforma Sprinklr pelos atendentes de midia sociais com assunto do caso', 
detalhamento            STRING  COMMENT 'Categoria gerada na plataforma Sprinklr pelos atendentes de midia sociais com detalhamento do caso', 
motivo_engajamento      STRING  COMMENT 'Categoria gerada na plataforma Sprinklr pelos atendentes de midia sociais com motivo e engajamento do caso', 
has_brand_responded     STRING  COMMENT 'Mensagem teve uma resposta', 
sender_id               STRING  COMMENT 'Id do usuario que esta enviando a mensagem', 
sender_name             STRING  COMMENT 'Login do usuario que esta enviando a mensagem', 
sender_screenname       STRING  COMMENT 'Nome do usuario que esta enviando a mensagem', 
sender_location         STRING  COMMENT 'Localizacao do usuario que esta enviando a mensagem',
sender_url_profile      STRING  COMMENT 'URL do perfil do usuario que esta enviando a mensagem', 
sender_following        STRING  COMMENT 'Quantidade de seguintes do usuario que esta enviando a mensagem', 
sender_followers        STRING  COMMENT 'Quantidade de seguidores do usuario que esta enviando a mensagem', 
receiver_id             STRING  COMMENT 'Id do usuario que esta recebendo a mensagem', 
receiver_name           STRING  COMMENT 'Nome do usuario que esta recebendo a mensagem'
) stored as orc
location '/user/next/dev/sprinklr/external'
tblproperties ("orc.compress"="ZLIB");
```

Version of Hive: Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.7.0

I'm using Spark 1.6(because of the company that I'm working with) to write the orc files in the 'location'. The file is there and has the right content. I know that because I can read the content on a Dataframe using Spark.

However, when I use a simple query(SELECT * FROM ), the result is this:

```
$ hive -e "select * from dev.tru_sprinklr_rpt_platform_inbound_case"
2020-05-12 18:13:10,235 WARN  [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: The hbase-prefix-tree 
module jar containing PrefixTreeCodec is not present.  Continuing without it.

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-log4j.properties
OK
Time taken: 1.134 seconds
WARN: The method class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.
WARN: Please see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#release for an explanation
```

As you can see, nothing is returning even with orc files(directories actually) in te right path on HDFS.

I tried to use this command with the hope was just Hive that needs to update the metadata: 
    MSCK REPAIR TABLE dev.tru_sprinklr_rpt_platform_inbound_case

But nothing changed!

I've trying to include this line before the create table but, nothing changed too!
    ADD JAR /jars/hive-orc-2.2.0.jar;

I've read similar questions but no anwsers worked for me.

Any suggestions, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks good to read data, but may be because of wrong column orders or wrong datatype, your data not reading the data and blank is coming.

I have faced similar issue and that was for wrong column orders. It is strange because [ORC incorporate schema details](https://orc.apache.org/docs/types.html).

Comment: I've checked again using the command `hive --orcfiledump -d /user/next/dev/sprinklr/external/sprinklr-FUMwM2tzTb.orc/part-r-00000-a5086502-4548-4469-8741-5c6b505e4e61.orc` comparing with the result of command `show create table`. They are identical in terms of column order and data types(all fields are string type)

Comment: I modified the table to have only one column(universal_message_id). Same result! Hive don't recognize the ORC file content.

Comment: @AndreCarneiro  Specify `/user/next/dev/sprinklr/external/sprinklr-FUMwM2tzTb.orc/` as `LOCATION` in `TABLE CREATE` command.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I figure out this too! I completely forgot that spark saves a directory with parts rather than file, unless you use a coalesce, what I don't want to. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This is tipically a data file error, maybe files don't have the right format or some fields don't have the right format or better said there are differences or inconsistencies between the table structure and the data. Please try to check out the data files, there is an utility in Hive to check orc files.

As an example you can see this link:

[On HDFS, I want to display normal text for a hive table stored in ORC format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61305838/on-hdfs-i-want-to-display-normal-text-for-a-hive-table-stored-in-orc-format/61318059#61318059)

And the Hive documentation:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC#LanguageManualORC-ORCFileDumpUtility

Comment: I've used the utilitary you suggested. I didn't see nothing that was different between table and orc file, including column names, order and type. I modified the table to have only one column(universal_message_id). Same result! Hive don't recognize the ORC file content.

Comment: Yeah! that's weird because I'm working with a cloudera quickstart vm and orc files runs nicely. I can't figure out what's happening.

Comment: Foud the problem! Spark is saving a directory with parts of the file. I forgot this!